# Reversing a simple function in a "creative" way in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, reverse

I need some help :D.

I have written this procedure that turns a string into a list of numbers:

```
(define (string->encodeable string)
   (map convert-to-base-four (map string->int (explode string))))
```

I need a function that does the exact opposite. In other words, takes a list of a list of numbers in base 4, turn it into base 10, and then creates a string. Is there a "creative" way to reverse my function or do I have to write every opposite step again. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard Scheme implementation using [SRFI-1 List library](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (only (srfi :1) fold))

(define (base4-list->number b4l)
  (fold (lambda (digit acc)
          (+ digit (* acc 4)))
        0
        b4l))

(base4-list->number '(1 2 3))
; ==> 27
```

It works the same in `#lang racket` but then you `(require srfi/1)`

PS: I'm not entirely sure if your conversion from base 10 to base 4 is the best solution. Imagine the number `95` which should  turn into `(1 1 3 3)`. I would have done it with `unfold-right` in SRFI-1.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you define "creative". In Racket you could do something like this:

```
(define (f lst)
  (number->string
   (for/fold ([r 0]) ([i (in-list lst)])
     (+ i (* r 4)))))
```

then

```
> (f '(1 0 0))
"16"
> (f '(1 3 2 0 2 1 0 0 0))
"123456"
```

Answer (score 0):

The relationship you're looking for is called an [*isomorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism)

The other answers here demonstrate this using folds but at your level I think you should be doing this on your own – or at least until you're more familiar with the language

```
#lang racket

(define (base10 ns)
  (let loop ((ns ns) (acc 0))
    (if (empty? ns)
        acc
        (loop (cdr ns) (+ (car ns)
                          (* 4 acc))))))

(displayln (base10 '(3 0)))               ; 12
(displayln (base10 '(3 1)))               ; 13
(displayln (base10 '(3 2)))               ; 14
(displayln (base10 '(3 3)))               ; 15
(displayln (base10 '(1 0 0)))             ; 16
(displayln (base10 '(1 3 2 0 2 1 0 0 0))) ; 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

@naomik's answer mentioned [*isomorphisms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism). When you construct an isomorphism, you're constructing a function and its inverse together. By composing and joining isomorphisms together, you can construct both directions "at once."

```
;; Converts between a base 4 list of digits (least significant first, most
;; significant last) and a number.
(define iso-base4->number
  (iso-lazy
   (iso-cond

     ;; an iso-cond clause has an A-side question, an A-to-B isomorphism,
     ;; and a B-side question. Here the A-side is empty and the B-side is 
     ;; zero.
     [empty?  (iso-const '() 0)  zero?]

     ;; Here the A-side is a cons, and the B-side is a positive number.
     [cons?
      (iso-join
        cons
        (λ (r q) (+ (* 4 q) r))
        [first  iso-identity       (curryr remainder 4)]
        [rest   iso-base4->number  (curryr quotient 4)])
      positive?])))
```

This code contains all the information needed to convert a base 4 list into a number and back again. (The base 4 lists here are ordered from least-significant digit to most-significant digit. This is reversed from the normal direction, but that's okay, that can be fixed outside.)

The first cond case maps empty to zero and back again.

The second cond case maps `(cons r q)` to `(+ (* 4 q) r)` and back again, but with `q` converted between lists and numbers recursively.

Just as a cons cell can be split using `first` and `rest`, a positivive number can be split into its "remainder-wrt-4" and its "quotient-wrt-4". Since the remainder is a fixed size and the quotient is an arbitrary size, the `remainder` is analogous to `first` and the `quotient` is analogous to `rest`.

The `first` and `remainder` don't need to be converted into each other, so the first `iso-join` clause uses `iso-identity`, the isomorphism that does nothing.

```
[first  iso-identity       (curryr remainder 4)]
```

The `rest` and `quotient` do need to be converted though. The rest is a list of base 4 digits in least-to-most-significant order, and the quotient is the number corresponding to it. The conversion between them is `iso-base4->number`.

```
[rest   iso-base4->number  (curryr quotient 4)]
```

If you're interested in how these isomorphism forms like `iso-const`, `iso-cond`, and `iso-join` are defined, [*this gist*](https://gist.github.com/AlexKnauth/30e15a518d85b0b38d9dd7645f7253b9)  contains everything needed for this example.